# Enum.ToObject with "invalid" int value - how to fix it

Tags: c#, enums

I am trying to convert an object to an Enum I am getting through reflection and only have the Type information of it.

Here is my enum:

```
public enum Foo : int
{
    Apple = 1,
    Banana = 2,
    Orange = 3,
}
```

Now in my method I am trying to set an object value, with the an enum the information I have is type info and an "original" value which is the int.

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar()
    {
        var enumValue = GetEnumValue(typeof(Foo), 0);
    }

    public object GetEnumValue(Type enumType, object value)
    {
        return Enum.ToObject(enumType, value);
    }
}
```

This code is working so far but there is a "little" problem, you may have noticed that I am declaring fix values for my `Foo Enum (Apple = 1, Banana = 2, Orange = 3)` and in my `GetEnumValue(typeof(Foo), 0)` my second parameter is **0**.

**0** isn't a value specified in my Enum the `Enum.ToObject()` doesn't throw an exception or what ever it only works.

I would like to fix this so that if the `GetEnumValue` gets called with an invalid value the return value should be the default enum value.

Default enum value should be on a nullable enum null and on non-nullable the first enum so Apple in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the constructor you have place this:

```
        public Bar(int value)
        {
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Foo), value))
            {
                var enumValue = GetEnumValue(typeof(Foo), value);
            }
            else
            {
                var enumValue = GetEnumValue(typeof(Foo), 1);

                //or like this...
                var enumValue1 = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foo)).GetValue(0);
            }
        }
```

I left it very explicit so you get what is happening.